# Set an NSTimer to fire once in the future

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nstimer

How do I set up an NSTimer to fire once in the future (say, 30 seconds). So far, I have only managed to set it so it fires immediately, and then at intervals.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The method you want to use is:

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval) seconds target:(id) target selector:(SEL) aSelector userInfo:(id) userInfo repeats:(BOOL) repeats
```

with `repeats == NO` arguments and `seconds == 30`. This will create the timer and schedule it. It will fire only once, in 30 seconds (and not immediately).

Answer (score 6):

You can set the timer with your future date, and set repeats to NO

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval) seconds
                                     target:(id) target
                                   selector:(SEL) aSelector
                                   userInfo:(id) userInfo
                                    repeats:(BOOL) repeats
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this class method to schedule timer.

```
 +(NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds
    target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo
    repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

**Parameters**
**seconds**
The number of seconds between firings of the timer. If seconds is less than or equal to 0.0, this method chooses the nonnegative value of 0.1 milliseconds instead.
**target**
The object to which to send the message specified by aSelector when the timer fires. The target object is retained by the timer and released when the timer is invalidated.
**aSelector**
The message to send to target when the timer fires. The selector must have the following   signature:
- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer
The timer passes itself as the argument to this method.
**userInfo**
The user info for the timer. The object you specify is retained by the timer and released when the timer is invalidated. This parameter may be nil.
**repeats**
If YES, the timer will repeatedly reschedule itself until invalidated. If NO, the timer will be invalidated after it fires.
**Example**

```
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
             target:self
             selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
             userInfo:[self userInfo]
             repeats:NO];
```

The timer is automatically fired by the run loop after 2 seconds. [Timer Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html)