# iOS: Get NSTimer to fire 5 seconds from now

Tags: ios, nstimer, nstimeinterval

**THE SCENARIO** I am working on an app that needs to fire off a method 5 seconds after a button is tapped.

**THE CODE** This is the code that is supposed to set off the `controlTimerExpire` method after 5 seconds

```
NSDate *fiveSecondsFromNow = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:5.0f];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [fiveSecondsFromNow timeIntervalSinceNow];

controlTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(controlTimerExpire) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

// I ALSO TRIED THIS; HARDCODING IT LIKE BELOW

controlTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f target:self selector:@selector(controlTimerExpire) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

**THE ISSUE** `controlTimerExpire` get fired immediately after the button is tapped. There needs to be 5 seconds in-between the button tap and the `controlTimerExpire` method firing.

**THE QUESTION** Why is this firing immediately and not firing 5 seconds from now?

**LINKS** What I have done above is exactly what these links below say to do, yet, it does not yield the same result as in the links. WHY?

[Set an NSTimer to fire once in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765044/set-an-nstimer-to-fire-once-in-the-future)

[How to call a method every x seconds in Objective-C using NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454583/how-to-call-a-method-every-x-seconds-in-objective-c-using-nstimer)

Comment: I deserve to have my question voted down. Sorry for the mix up guys.

Comment: BTW - It would be so much simpler to use `dispatch_after` for this. No timer needed. No extra method needed.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet but that sounds promising. Thanks @rmaddy! You are a god among men.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue actually was further down in my code I was calling `[controlTimer fire];`. That was left over because I was trying to get it to work and I left that in there by mistake. Whoops, just wasted half an hour. So for you guys that may be having the same issue, all you need is to set the

`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f target:self selector:@selector(controlTimerExpire) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];`

and you don't need to explicitly call `fire` because the `scheduled` part of the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` will fire the selector for you based on the time interval you set.

Answer (score 3):

Your whole NSDate calculation is wrong and unnecessary. NSTimer takes seconds. If you want to fire 5 seconds from now, just pass `5`.